# How to combine 2 boxes (not grouping) in visio

Tags: merge, visio

I have a diagram like this - 
[image]

But I want to have a single box for SI-2130, 2131 & 2132, something like this. How do I do that. I tried various things but I'm stuck.

[image]

I do see these kind of diagrams, See this figure - but not sure how they did it

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit the shape's geometry section.

First, ensure you have Developer Mode enabled. Right-click on the shape you want to edit and select Edit Shapesheet.

Near the top of the dit window you will see a Geometry section, this determines the shape and outline of your shape. You will need to insert new lines in this section for the new vertices.

For details on how to do this use your search engine on the details of the Geometry section.

Here is a starting place for you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/visio/about-the-shapesheet-spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Thanks peter. Yea, I got to know about the developer tab, and the options for 'union/intersection/subtract', etc. I could do this using this approach easily